# Estou recebendo essa mensagem de erro >>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of null (linha 5, arquivo "Código")

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-sheets, planilha, sum, background-color

Estou tentando no Google Sheets somar os valores de células que possuam fundo da mesma cor. O problema é que o código está me retornando a seguinte mensagem:

" TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of null (linha 5, arquivo "Código") "

Não sei como resolver, sou bem iniciante. Se alguém puder me ajudar. Segue abaixo o código.

```
function sumByColor(sumRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\;/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var sumValues = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getValues(); 
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\;(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var totalValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        if ((typeof sumValues[i][k]) == 'number')
          totalValue = totalValue + (sumValues[i][k]);
  return totalValue;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nas linhas 5 e 8 mude `;` para `,`. No Brasil esse é o separador padrão.

```
function sumByColor(sumRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var sumValues = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getValues(); 
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var totalValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        if ((typeof sumValues[i][k]) == 'number')
          totalValue = totalValue + (sumValues[i][k]);
  return totalValue;
};
```